# How to do nested sorting within dense_rank

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I have used the dense rank to group the items in the table into 3 days bucket. Example: 22-24 April will be 'tight up' together and assigned priority as 4.

[image]
Question:

1. I need to do the further sorting on Planning_package based on the QTYORDERED. The final result for priority 4 as below. 
   [image]

The sql I use to perform the sorting as below. Anyone can help can help to do the further sorting on planning_package???
**

```
select SALESORDERID, ITEM, PLANNING_PACKAGE, GENERIC_PACKAGE, QTYORDERED,
DMD_TYPE_CD, ORDER_TYPE_CD, PRIORITY_NBR,PROMISEDAVAILDATE,
dense_rank()
over
(
order by
    round((
            case when dmd_type_cd = 'Netted Forecast'
                 then greatest(PROMISEDAVAILDATE, (to_date('22-Apr-14','DD-Mon-YY')+31)) 
                 else PROMISEDAVAILDATE end
            - (to_date('22-Apr-14','DD-Mon-YY')+1)) / 3, 0) desc
) as priority

from
TEST_SALESORDER_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple column to sort by the in `order by clause` - in your case it will be .... `order by priority , qtyordered desc`

If `priority` is an expression you can order by column position as well.